# Audio & video autoplay on chrome/Safari with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't play my audio automatically on mobile browser, i tried to start by muted true then onclick make it false but still not working.
same for my video as background on safari only the first frame is showing

I tried <video><source></video> and same for audio and specify type audio/mp3 video/mp4, and normal the src in video/audio

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { MusicNote, MusicOff } from '@mui/icons-material';
import song from '../Assets/song.mp3';

const MusicPlayer = () => {
    const [isMuted, setIsMuted] = useState(true);
    const audioRef = useRef(null);

    const toggleMute = () => {
        setIsMuted(!isMuted);
        audioRef.current.muted = !audioRef.current.muted;
    };

    return (
        <div className='audio'>
            <audio ref={audioRef} src={song} autoPlay loop muted />
            <div onClick={toggleMute}>{!isMuted ? <MusicNote /> : <MusicOff />}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default MusicPlayer;
################################
import video from '../Assets/video.MOV';

function VideoPlayer() {
    return (
        <div
            className='video'
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `
        <video
          loop
          muted
          autoplay
          playsinline
          src="${video}"
        />,
      `,
                // <video loop muted autoplay playsinline>
                //  <source src="./Assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                // </video>,
            }}></div>
    );
}
export default VideoPlayer;
```

Comment: Perhaps this will be of use to you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide